# Atmel AT91RM9200 compilers on Windows

Tags: compiler

I have an embedded Linux device based on the AT91RM9200. Its [manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0151c/ARM920T_TRM1_S.pdf) say that it is based on the ARM9TDMI architecture. Are there any compilers available for this CPU on windows ? (Note: I'm already developing application for this CPU on Linux but I want to try the Windows environment).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cross compile with the GCC tool-chain a good place to start looking is https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded or hhps://gcc.org or you can add the [GNU/ARM](http://gnuarm.com/files.html) tools to [MinGW Studio](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW) but if you are looking for a pre-built, ready to go solution & are prepared to pay for it the it could be worth looking at [CodeSourcery](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/).